# Removing the highlight when touching infoWindow adapter

Tags: android, google-maps

I've implemented a custom infoWindow which I programmed to display when touching a marker.

When I touch the infoWindow, it highlights in the default blue color (on Jelly bean) as stated by the Google Maps v2 API. The issue is that I can't seem to disable this highligh.

I have tried adding:

```
<android:clickable="false">
```

but it didn't work.

I also tried implementing the OnInfoWindowClickListener and overriding the onInfoWindowClick method, but this didn't work either.

> "Help me, Obi-Wan Kenobi. You're my only hope"

Comment: have u tried `android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`

Comment: have you tried: android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"?

Comment: tried putting all 3 of them in the XML but it still doesn't work :/ any more ideas?

Comment: Please check this link...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531578/how-to-customise-the-state-pressed-colour-of-an-infowindow-in-google-maps

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no API to do it (yet), there is an acknowledged issue in gmaps-api-issues:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4783

Hopefully, it will be possible soon